# Rapidly growing sequence with initial conditions

Tags: sequences-and-series

Take any integer less than 10, but greater than 1. That integer represents the number of digits of the next number in the sequence. If your integer = 9, the next integer must be any number with 9 digits

$100,000,000 < n < 999,999,999$

Sequence:

Let $X_0 = n$ where n is any integer such that $1 < n < 10$

$X_1 = \frac{10^{X_0}}{10}$

$X_2 = \frac{10^{X_1}}{10}$

$X_3 = \frac{10^{X_2}}{10}$

.
.
.

$X_n$ = $\frac{10^{X_n-1}}{10}$

This sequence grows very rapidly. If $X_0 = 2$, $X_1 = 10$, $X_2 = 1,000,000,000, X_3 = 10^{\frac{10^{10}}{10}} = big$. etc.

Is there a better way to represent this sequence mathematcially? I know that:

Number of digits $= \lfloor \log_{10}(|x|) + 1 \rfloor$

So, the number of digits in $X_1 = \lfloor \log_{10}(|\frac{10^{X_0}}{10}|) + 1 \rfloor = 2$, if we use the numbers above.

The number of digits in $X_2 = \left \lfloor \log_{10}\left( \left|\frac{10^{X_1}}{10} \right| \right) + 1 \right \rfloor = 10$

The number of digits in $X_3 = \lfloor \log_{10}(|\frac{10^{X_2}}{10}|) + 1 \rfloor = \lfloor \log_{10}(|\frac{10^{\frac{10^{10}}{10}}}{10}|) + 1 \rfloor =1,000,000,000$.

The number of digits in $X_0$ will always be 1.

I know that the number of digits is immediately visible, just by looking at the previous number in the sequence. But that function *mathematically* represents the number digits in the previous term.

So finally, is there a way to represent the entirety of this sequence in one equation? I feel like it isn't that difficult, I just can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: When it comes to notation, perhaps this helps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation